# DateTime difference from current date to figure out a past date

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to find a date (string) that is 5 years from current date in the past:-

DateTime.UtcNow.Date - DateString = 5 years

Can anyone help me formulate this into c# syntax?

Comment: DateTime has a method called AddYears to which you could pass a negative number (-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
var newDate = myDate.AddYears(-5);
```

Comment: Downvoter, why the downvote?

Comment: Ididn't downvote. Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 0):

You can [add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_addition.aspx) or [subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s85h2eca.aspx) a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) from a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) object to get another `DateTime` object.

```
var fiveYearsAgo = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromYears(5);
var fiveYearsFromNow = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromYears(5);
```